# How do I use ffmpeg to extract frames starting at a specific number?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've decided for some reason to upscale an entire 90-minute movie using AI. Problem is, I have several demo scenes that have already been upscaled, and I want to keep those frames rather than upscaling them again. Basically I want to export frames starting at a specific number, like `ffmpeg -i scene1.mp4 scene1/%10d+[starting number].jpg`. If the specified number were 1550, for example, the first frame it would export would be `0000001550.jpg`. I still want it to start at the first frame of the input video, though; the only things I want to change are the names of the output files. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-start_number` option for image2 muxer.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i scene1.mp4 -start_number 1550 scene1/%10d.jpg
```